# Как лучше получать информацию с сервера?

Tags: веб-сервер

Есть приложение (React.js), которое получает данные с сервера. Как лучше сделать: получить все данные сразу при запуске приложения (и сохранить в какое-нибудь хранилище) или получать их по необходимости по запросу? P.S. данные не меняются.

Comment: Зависит от объёма данных, если приложение маленькое и там немного данных, то можно одним запросом, если там большой поток данных, то лучше конечно подгружать.`Redux` как хранилище.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.